# Find partial derivatives of $f(x,y) = g(e^{xy^2}, \sin x+\cos y)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Find partial derivatives of $f(x,y) = g(e^{xy^2}, \sin x+\cos y)$, with $g:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ a differentiable function.

So I called $u(x,y) = e^{xy^2}$ and $v(x,y)=\sin x+\cos y$

Then, I calculated $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial g}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = y^2e^{xy^2}\frac{\partial g}{\partial u} + \cos x\frac{\partial g}{\partial v}$

And $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial g}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} = 2xye^{xy^2}\frac{\partial g}{\partial u} - \sin y\frac{\partial g}{\partial v}$

Now, I don't how to proceed, I have the derivatives in function of $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$, not only on $x$ and $y$.

Any help?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking, but you solved the problem.

Comment: I don't think so, because I created two functions, and I solved the derivatives based on these new functions. My answer is incomplete

Comment: This is one of the reasons I hate this very established notation. You should look at $\frac{\partial g}{\partial u}$ as the partial derivative of $g$ with respect to the first coordinate (note that this description is not only valid, but it doesn't depend on $u$ at all). Similarly for $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$, etc. I think the notation $\partial _1g$ and $\partial u_1$ is much better. $\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}$ would be $\partial _2g$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole point is that $\displaystyle\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$ and $\displaystyle\frac{\partial g}{\partial u}$ both means the directional derivatives of $g$ in the direction of $(1,0)$. This is just a matter of notation so that the chain rule becomes easier to keep in mind with the cancellation rule loved by the physicists.

I would like to emphasise on the points on which the partial derivatives are evaluated, one has:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)=\frac{\partial g}{\partial u}(u(x,y),v(x,y))\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x,y)+\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}(u(x,y),v(x,y))\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}(x,y).$$

Comment: As I commented to @Gud, I created the two functions $u$ and $v$, so they shouldn't appear on the answer.

Comment: Have you read my answer? In $\displaystyle\frac{\partial g}{\partial u}$, $u$ is not a function. It means the first coordinates of $g$.

Comment: Yes, I read, I was just confused about the notation. I think I got it

Comment: You have already done the hard work! If you are still confused about what the notation means, try to think about the geometrical sense of the partial derivatives, it probably will get clearer. :)

Comment: @C.Falcon How about you also add the points to $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$? Up voted anyway.

Comment: @GitGud Added! Guess I only focused on the tricky point, ah ah!